# A step in the proof of Engel's theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am trying to understand the proof of Engel's theorem and I am stuck with the following step. Assuming we have an invariant element $v$ in $V$ a vector space carrying a representation of $L$, where $L$ acts by nilpotent operators. We want to find a basis of $V$ with respect to which every element of $L$ is upper triangular. This can be assumed to exist when $V$ has dimension $n$, then we look at the dim$(V) = n+1$ case. We quotient $V$ by the submodule $\mathbb{K}v$ and to get an $n$-dimensional representation of $L$, allowing us to apply the inductive hypothesis and conclude an $b_i$ upper triangular basis for $V/\mathbb{K}v$.

So far so good. But now one "lifts the basis" up to $V$, takes the union with $v$ to get a new basis
$$
v,b'_1, \dots, b'_{n}
$$
and bingo we are done! However I do not understand what this lifting process actually means. Sure we can choice of element $b'_i$ in the preimage of each $b_i$ and taking the union with $v$ gives a basis of $V$, but why is clear that $L$ acts on $b'_i$ to give an element in the span of $b'_{i+1}, \dots, b'_n$? I don't see why the lift still has the upper triangular property . . .  I guess nilpotency comes into play here somewhere, bt I cannot see how . . .

Comment: The correct statement is *$L$ acts on $b_{i}'$  to give an element in the span of $b_{i+1}', \dots ,b_{n}', \color{red}{v}$.* Also, it is easier to order the new basis as $b'_1, \dots, b'_{n}, \color{red}{v}$.

Comment: @Andreas: I think it is now clear. Thanks a lot for pointing out this trick!

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: Maybe make that an answer so Dyke can accept it.

Comment: Yes, please do, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: Sorry, I have been busy. Just posted my comment as an answer. Thanks @DykeAcland, Torstein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the new basis as $b'_1, \dots, b'_{n}, \color{magenta}{v}$. Then you see that $L$ acts on $b_{i}'$ to give an element of $b_{i+1}', \dots ,b_{n}', \color{magenta}{v}$.